# How do I handle overlapping, but transparent picture-boxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I want to make a small tool for a friend of mine. The goal of this is to load a character out of one of his favourite computer games from an internet source and to create a viewer, for which I download image icons etc. from the internet.

So far it's working pretty good, however, I came to a problem right here:

[image]

As you can see - I painted the borders of the PictureBoxes - they are overlapping, and blocking the other item from being displayed (the one which is partly visible in the second bordered box).

Both are stored as .png files.

This is the code to create them:

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
{
    Name = "pictureBox"+item.Key,
    Size = new Size(pictureBoxWidth, pictureBoxHeight),
    Location = new Point(pictureBoxLocationX, pictureBoxLocationY),
    Visible = true,
    Image = itemIcon,
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
};
```

The coordinates are alright, also the image is fine. However, it is pretty large, even if icons like the one fully visible doesn't even need the huge box.

The boxes have these attributes:

64px width
128px height

How can I possibly show both items, instead of having one item overlapping the other one? It would have to be some kind of transparency which is only applied to the next layer, which would be - in this case - either the box with the other item or the background.

I already tried the Parent-solution, but whenever I do this, the box of the parent is too small to move the child icon back to its original point.

Answer (score 4):

This is the eternal PictureBox question, time to do something about it.  It supports transparency just fine but it is emulated as in all Winforms controls. It asks its Parent to draw itself to provide the background pixels.  Works fine but it doesn't check if it overlaps any other PictureBoxes.

That's fixable, you just need to override its OnPaintBackground() method and include the overlapped ones.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto the your form, replacing the existing pictureboxes.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox {
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        for (int index = this.Parent.Controls.Count - 1; index > this.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this); --index) {
            var ctl = this.Parent.Controls[index] as PictureBox;
            if (ctl == null) continue;
            var clip = ctl.RectangleToClient(this.RectangleToScreen(this.DisplayRectangle));
            clip.Intersect(ctl.DisplayRectangle);
            if (clip.Width == 0 || clip.Height == 0) continue;
            var save = e.Graphics.Save();
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(ctl.Left - this.Left, ctl.Top - this.Top);
            using (var rgn = new Region(clip)) {
                e.Graphics.Clip = rgn;
                InvokePaintBackground(ctl, e);
                InvokePaint(ctl, e);
            }
            e.Graphics.Restore(save);
        }               
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, that does not quite work for me. I replaced my PictureBox picture = new PictureBox with PictureBoxEx picture = new PictureBoxEx, but that won't change anything so far. All my PictureBoxes are being created at runtime. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Or do I have to - in order to make this work - use the PictureBoxEx.Parent attribute?

Comment: Hans, I think you should be drawing siblings backwards (`for (int i = this.Parent.Controls.Count - 1; i > index; i--) ...` and remove the `CreateParams` override.  @Sossenbinder: After adding a new picture box at runtime, you'd better call `BringToFront` method of the added control.

Comment: You are right about the sibling order.  The CreateParams override is necessary to ensure the pbox gets repainted when overlapped boxes get moved or updated.

Comment: I see. However at runtime when you stack a couple boxes it flickers like crazy and doesn't work at all. Just FYI.

Comment: awful code doesn't work at all I'm just getting some flickering http://prntscr.com/avhx9d